# Xamarin Android app 'Bad request' when making API call to Web Service

Tags: c#, android, .net, web-services, xamarin

I have created 3 applications. A Xamarin Mobile app, Web Service, and a Console app (test app). I can register a user with my Console app by making a Post call to the Web Service app but when I move the exact same code to my Xamarin android app it gives me 'Bad Request' response. I have published the Web Service to my local IIS in order to access the Web Service With IP address.

```
public async Task<bool> RegisterAsync(string email, string password, string password2)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            RegisterBindingModel user = new RegisterBindingModel
            {
                Email = email,
                Password = password,
                ConfirmPassword = password2
            };


            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var responce = await client.PostAsync("http://192.168.0.114/RainDropWebService/api/Account/Register", content);
            return responce.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
```

What is the difference between calling it from the Console app where it will works and the Xamarin app where it does not work? If I go to my Xamarin Emulator's browser I am able to access the Web App with the Ip Address

Comment: Is your device connected to the same network as your local server? Bear in mind that when you use your web app or console app, you run it on the same device as your local device, therefore you obviously have access to it. This isnt the case with your mobile device. You might have to enable certain settings on your server/network. I will be following this question btw, because I will be implementing same thing soon into my app.

Comment: Thanx for the responce Woj, Yes my phone was on the same network. After a long time I have manage to fix my issue. The password i supplied when registering from the phone did not have a number... I was just being lazy when typing the password in all the time and did not have the right error displaying from the Webservice on the phone sceen. Sorry About this it was just me making life hard for myself again...